# nUnit : throw HttpResponseException and access embedded HttpResponseMessage

Tags: exception, nunit, httpresponse, http-status-codes

```
Assert.Throws<HttpResponseException>(() => ApiController.Post("query-params-string", "request-body-json"));
```

Now I'd like to view the contents of `HttpResponseException.Response.StatusCode`

Any way to do this ?

Answer (score 2):

```
HttpResponseException ex = Assert.Throws<HttpResponseException>(() => ApiController.Post("query-params-string", "request-body-json"));<br>
Assert.AreEqual(ex.Response.StatusCode, HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
```